# How to display metadata about single commit in git?

Tags: git

I'd like to parse meta information from git repository. I'd like to fetch a single information for a commit, as in

```
git log --pretty=format:%an HEAD^..HEAD
```

Problem is, this is not working for the first commit in repository.

```
git show --pretty=format:%an HEAD^..HEAD
```

is also close to what I want, except I'm not interested in parsing actual diff.

Any idea how to make git log work for the first commit or how to disable git show from showing commit content?

Or, is there any better way how to retrieve metadata about given commit?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Supply the quiet option to show to suppress the diff.

```
git show --quiet HEAD
```

So for your example, author name:

```
git show --quiet --pretty=format:%an
```

Comment: In git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0, `--quiet` is simply ignored. Here, `-s` works well

Comment: `--quiet` is not documented in the man page, so probably deprecated in favor of `-s`.

Answer (score 15):

```
git --no-pager show -s --format='%an <%ae>' COMMIT
```

- `--no-pager` [supresses the pager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183920/873282)
- `-s` [suppresses diff output](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt--s); short for `--no-patch`
- `%an` is the author name
- `%ae` is the author email

(Taken from [quora.com](http://www.quora.com/Git-revision-control/Whats-the-simplest-git-command-to-get-a-commits-author-and-their-email-address-if-available))

Comment: At least `git show -s` [is documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#git-show--s). It's short for `--no-patch`, and as the manual says, it suppresses the diff output.

Answer (score 1):

**`git log -n 1 --format='%an'`**

`-n 1` restricts the log to a single commit.

Does the same as `git show --quiet`, although I prefer it a bit since it is documented on `man git-log` while `--quiet` is not documented on `man git-show` as of 2.17.

Also note that you can golf even better with show with the short form of `--quiet`:

```
git show -q --format='%an'
```