# How do I prevent 'git diff' from using a pager?

Tags: git

Is there a command line switch to pass to `git diff` and other commands that use the `less` pager by default? I know these methods exist:

- `git diff | cat`... removes all syntax highlighting
- `git config --global core.pager cat` sets the pager in the global .gitconfig to `cat`
- `export GIT_PAGER=cat`

But I would prefer a command line switch.

Comment: Note: `core.pager 'less -+F -+X'` would be a more recent way to remove those options. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18781512/6309).

Comment: "less -+F -+X" is the magical setting to remove the annoying "...skipping..." markers in long logs. Thanks a lot for those options, you saved my day!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352049/always-use-the-pager-for-git-diff

Comment: See related question on using `less` with git (it varies dependent on `less` version): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107315/less-quit-if-one-screen-without-no-init

Comment: Looking for a solution on Windows? @Jaredcheeda's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399465/8604951 works .

Answer (score 1029, accepted):

`--no-pager` to Git will tell it to not use a pager. Passing the option `-F` to `less` will tell it to not page if the output fits in a single screen.

Make sure that you add `--no-pager` or `-P` **before** your command, as in `git --no-pager log...`.

Usage:

```
git --no-pager diff
```

Other options from the comments include:

```
# Set an evaporating environment variable to use 'cat' for your pager
GIT_PAGER=cat git diff

# Tells 'less' not to paginate if less than a page
export LESS="-F -X $LESS"
# ...then Git as usual
git diff

# short option alternative
git -P diff
```

Comment: I don't see why not. I have no idea how it would react if used for a predicate that doesn't need a pager at all though.

Comment: Or use GIT_PAGER or PAGER environment variables, or `core.pager` git config variable.

Comment: Keep in mind that you must add --add-pager *before* your command, as in "git --no-pager log --format=blah"

Comment: Also, if your terminal clears the screen after exiting less you'll want to add `-E` to your `less` options to make `-F` usable.

Comment: the `--pager` option is not available to the `git shortlog` command

Comment: @mgalgs much of the point of using less is so it only uses the secondary screen, rather than scrolling useful context off the screen. I.e. -E is an anti-feature much of the time.

Comment: @barry actually I don't use it that way anymore. But it works for some people (like myself two years ago).

Comment: Note that if you want to include `--no-pager` in an alias, you have to prefix the command with it, and to avoid an error, you have to make an alias like this: `git config alias.foo '!git --no-pager foo'`. Somewhat confusing. Simply aliasing to `'--no-pager foo'` won't work.

Comment: See Joseph Cheek's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23224608/2562319) below for reasons *not* to use --no-pager in an alias, along with info on the pager.alias system recommended for use instead of that.

Comment: I don't get how this has been here for so long without anyone mentioning that you should use double quotes in all shells I'm aware of to expand the variables.  On an unrelated topic, who makes these rules: *"Edits must be at least 6 characters. Is there something else to  improve in this post?"*

Comment: To remove the paging: git config --global core.pager '' ... or use the paging git config --global core.pager 'more' ... git config --global core.pager 'less'

Comment: Just a note, in case you're using a command that doesn't accept the `--no-pager` flag (such as `git show`). You can simply pipe the command through the linux command `cat` to stdout. Example: `git show HEAD | cat -`.  EDIT: Oops, just read the rest of OP's question and saw this was already known... carry on!

Comment: @JimStewart I found `git config alias.foo '-c core.pager=cat foo'` to work just fine. But as you point out, it complains with a straight `--no-pager foo`.

Comment: `--no-pager` can also be shortened to `-P`

Comment: @JimStewart is `!` -reason subcommand- needed here?

Comment: Should I put it in the `.bashrc`: `LESS="-F -X $LESS"`. How would I use it? Is LESS a var or an executable or both?

Comment: Note that some old versions of git used to allow `git diff --no-pager ...` but the correct syntax is `git --no-pager diff ...`.

Comment: For the first part/half: Is it a permanent (configuration) change? Global? Per repository? Can you make it clearer in your answer?

Comment: `LESS="-F $LESS"` was exactly what I needed - thanks!!!

Answer (score 383):

As a previous answer mentioned, passing the `-F` option to `less` causes it to quit if the content is less than one screen. However, after doing so, the screen is reset, and you end up not seeing the content.

The `-X` option does away with that behaviour. So, I use the following to enable conditional paging based on the amount of content:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less -F -X"
```

Comment: Note: I had to use `git config --global --add core.pager "less -F -X"` in git `1.8.0.2`, the one above didn't work.

Comment: Great! Also to make it behave so not only with git but all programs add something like `export LESS="-RFX"` to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

Comment: Thank you for this; I've been plagued by an option in which git would truncate the first line from the output, and then get out of sync such that going down one line and then up one line would cause the 1st line of the correct to occupy the top, followed by the 3rd line from the correct output. Anyway, specifying this option resolved that issue. So bizarre.

Comment: If using Git For Windows (which uses less built by Greenwood Software), the parameter you need is -E  (source: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#dashe )

Comment: git specific option without requiring to change the functionality of `less` for the entire shell session. My final command was `git config --global core.pager "less -FXR"`.

Comment: Thanks! No idea why, but I already had this desired behaviour using Bash on Mac until I switched to Zsh. No less alias or gitconfig line existed. Anyway this answer fixed it.

Comment: It seems `-X` is not needed in my case at least (preferred since then output from commands like `git log` gets cleared after closing the pager). I'm using `-FKR`.

Comment: Yes, as I explained in my answer, I prefer the screen not to be reset before and after the pager starts and exits, especially if it all fits in one screen, which is exactly what `-X` does. Don't use it if you don't like that. I like it because this way I can refer to things like git SHAs by looking at the result of previous git commands in my history without having to type the command again. Each to his/her own.

Comment: As of December 2017 if you are using version 530 of less or higher, you do not need `-X`, [here is a post from unix SE explaining this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107355/121116). `less -F` will produce the desired behavior.

Comment: Well, this still sucks. I would like it to avoid pager when fits the screen, but use pager and reset if it doesn't. Right now with -+X it works well when it doesn't fit screen and resets it after quit, but then if it fits the screen the output is not being seen - which is ridiculous.

Comment: I think reset shouldn't apply if pager is not being used, and should apply otherwise.

Answer (score 240):

Use

```
git config --global core.pager cat
```

to get rid of a pager for all commands for all repositories.

You can also disable paging for single Git subcommands by using `pager.<cmd>` setting instead of `core.pager`, and you can change your settings per Git repository (omit `--global`).

See `man git-config` and search for `pager.<cmd>` for details.

Comment: The question was not how to disable pager altogether but how to disable it for the grep subcommand. 

mtahmed's answer is perfect.

Comment: This might be what the extended explanation asked but this is what I was looking for and it was one of the top Google results so thanks @geekQ

Comment: This would be terrible if you did `git log` in a repository with a large number of commits. Or worse, `git log -p` -- you'd get the entire set of commit diffs dumped into your terminal.

Answer (score 100):

You can disable/enable pagers for specific outputs in the global configuration as well:

```
git config --global pager.diff false
```

Or to set the core.pager option, just provide an empty string:

```
git config --global core.pager ''
```

This is better in my opinion than setting it to `cat` as you say.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me `git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)`

Comment: This is what i wanted because other commands disable the pager completely, but this is the only answer that disables only for `git diff` while leaving it working for other commands

Comment: as of this writing ... on Windows / PowerShell I had to manually edit `code "$($env:UserProfile)\.gitconfig"` and add `pager = ` under the `[core]` settings.  The answer worked for my current powershell session but didn't seem to save the setting anywhere so it was effective on the next launch.

Comment: To selectively page other options, use `git config --global pager.log "less -F -X"` or similar

Comment: This is best option when/if you're using similar .gitconfig for Windows and Linux; though git-for-windows do have `cat` and `less`, it may not have `more`; disabling and/or forcing to nothing is more portable to multi-platform without guessing and/or bothering to ask "are you Linux or Windows?"

Comment: NB: on Windows, using single quotes in the last command doesn't work, but double quotes do: `git config --global core.pager ""`

Comment: Worked great on git version 2.39.2

Answer (score 79):

The recent changes in the documentation mention a different way of removing a default option for `less` ("default options" being `FRSX`).

For this question, this would be (git 1.8+)

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager 'less -+F -+X'
```

For example, [Dirk Bester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843127/dirk-bester) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager/18781512?noredirect=1#comment44696310_18781512):

```
export LESS="$LESS -FRXK"
```

> so that I get colored diff with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> quit from `less`.

[Wilson F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35305/wilson-f) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager/18781512#comment53299964_18781512) and in [his question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231427/is-there-a-way-for-less-to-truncate-lines-and-still-exit-after-1-screen) that:

> less supports horizontal scrolling, so when lines are chopped off, less disables quit-if-one-screen so that the user can still scroll the text to the left to see what was cut off.

---

Those modifications were already visible in git 1.8.x, as illustrated in "[Always use the pager for `git diff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352224/6309)" (see the comments). 
But the documentation just got reworded ([for git 1.8.5 or 1.9, Q4 2013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/992c38644a4b001bdc89b5b5008fc5f6674ed5b7)).

> Text viewer for use by Git commands (e.g., 'less').
>   The value is meant to be interpreted by the shell.
>
> The order of preference is:
>
> - the `$GIT_PAGER` environment variable,
> - then `core.pager` configuration,
> - then `$PAGER`,
> - and then the default chosen at compile time (usually 'less').
>
> When the `LESS` environment variable is unset, Git sets it to `FRSX`
>   (if `LESS` environment variable is set, Git does not change it at all).
>
> **If you want to selectively override Git's default setting for `LESS`, you can set `core.pager` to e.g. `less -+S`**.
>   This will be passed to the shell by Git, which will translate the final command to `LESS=FRSX less -+S`. The environment tells the command to set the `S` option to chop long lines but the command line resets it to the default to fold long lines.

---

See [commit 97d01f2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97d01f2a8880702c84a20632a6748671bcbaf8d5) for the reason behind the new documentation wording:

### config: rewrite `core.pager` documentation

> The text mentions `core.pager` and `GIT_PAGER` without giving the overall picture of precedence.  Borrow a better description from the [`git var`(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-var) documentation.
>
> The use of the mechanism to allow system-wide, global and per-repository configuration files is not limited to this particular variable.  Remove it to clarify the paragraph.
>
> Rewrite the part that explains how the environment variable `LESS` is set to Git's default value, and how to selectively customize it.

---

Note: [commit b327583](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3275838d969b7ecb91aae584226fccbeb046aca) ([Matthieu Moy `moy`](https://github.com/moy), April 2014, for git 2.0.x/2.1, Q3 2014) will remove the S by default:

#### pager: remove 'S' from $LESS by default

> By default, Git used to set `$LESS` to `-FRSX` if `$LESS` was not set by the user.
>   The `FRX` flags actually make sense for Git (`F` and `X` because sometimes the output Git pipes to less is short, and `R` because Git pipes colored output).
>   The `S` flag (chop long lines), on the other hand, is not related to Git and is a matter of user preference. **Git should not decide for the user to change `LESS`'s default**.
>
> More specifically, the `S` flag harms users who review untrusted code within a pager, since a patch looking like:
>
> ```
> -old code;
> +new good code; [... lots of tabs ...] malicious code;
> ```
>
> would appear identical to:
>
> ```
> -old code;
> +new good code;
> ```
>
> Users who prefer the old behavior can still set the $LESS environment variable to `-FRSX` explicitly, or set core.pager to '`less -S`'.

The documentation will read:

> The environment does not set the `S` option but the command line does, instructing less to truncate long lines.
>   Similarly, setting `core.pager` to `less -+F` will deactivate the `F` option specified by the environment from the command-line, deactivating the "`quit if one screen`" behavior of `less`.
>   One can specifically activate some flags for particular commands: for example, setting `pager.blame` to `less -S` enables line truncation only for `git blame`.

Comment: @CoreDumpError note: the next Git (2.0.X or 2.1) won't chop line **by default**! See my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks. This let me figure out that I want   export LESS="$LESS -FRXK"  so that I get colored diff with ctrl-c quit from less.

Comment: @DirkBester Interesting suggestion. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Here's a puzzle (well, it is to me): when I set `less` to quit for <1 screen and _not_ chop lines (i.e. `less -F -+S`), I get returned to my command prompt after I run the log command. However, if I _do_ have it chop lines (i.e. remove `-+S`), _and any lines get chopped_, then when it ends, it _doesn't_ quit immediately, but prints `END` and waits for me to press `q`. Is there a way to chop lines and still exit from `less` automatically after less than a screen?

Comment: @WilsonF I don't know, but that sounds like a good question: why not make it a question instead of leaving it here, buried in comments?

Comment: Yes, I should have. So, I did, thanks! http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231427/is-there-a-way-for-less-to-truncate-lines-and-still-exit-after-1-screen

Comment: For anyone who finds this and is interested but can't be bothered to follow the link ;-) : it turns out that `less` supports horizontal scrolling (maybe everyone knows this, but I didn't), so when lines are chopped off, `less` disables `quit-if-one-screen` so that the user can still scroll the text to the left to see what was cut off.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me with Git version 2.1.4 on Linux:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager cat
```

This makes Git use `cat` instead of `less`. `cat` just dumps the output of `diff` to the screen without any paging.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy  I thought it was pretty clear that I was answering the question asked.  Seems like some users like to run around flagging short answers for fun.  I'll add some text.

Answer (score 12):

Regarding the disabled color when piping:

Use `--color` to avoid that coloring is disabled.

`git diff --color | less -R`

Or configure it forced on (in e.g. .gitconfig):

```
[color]
        ui = on
```

`git diff | less -R`

For non-color tools, then use:

`git diff --no-color | some-primitive-tool`

Exporting environment variable `LESS=-R` (in e.g. .bashrc) turns on color support by default in "less":

`git diff | less`

Comment: Note that git will set the `LESS` environment variable to `FRSX` when calling the pager, if it is unset.

Answer (score 11):

I like to disable paging from time to time, when I know the output is not very long. For this, I found a neat trick using Git aliases:

```
git config --global --add alias.n '!git --no-pager'
```

Or add the following to the `[alias]` section of ~/.gitconfig:

```
n = !git --no-pager
```

This means that you can use the prefix `n` to turn off paging for any Git command, i.e.:

```
git n diff # Show the diff without pager
git n log -n 3 # Show the last three commits without pager
git n show v1.1 # Show information about a tag
```

Comment: -P also does no-pager

Answer (score 10):

You can add an alias to diff with its own pager with pager.alias, like so:

```
[alias]
  dc = diff
  dsc = diff --staged
[pager]
  dc = cat
  dsc = cat
```

This will keep the color on and use 'cat' as the pager when invoked at 'git dc'.

Also, things *not* to do:

- use `--no-pager` in your alias. Git (1.8.5.2, Apple Git-48) will complain that you are trying to modify the environment.
- use a shell with `!sh` or `!git`. This will bypass the environment error, above, but it will reset your working directory (for the purposes of this command) to the top-level Git directory, so any references to a local file will not work if you are already in a subdirectory of your repository.

Comment: +1 This technique is useful when you want to navigate by commit after `git log` but not `git log --oneline`. Use `pager.log = less -FXR +/^commit.*`, while special-casing the `--oneline` option with `alias.l1 = log --oneline` and `pager.l1 = less -FXR`.

Answer (score 9):

As it says on **man git**, you can use `--no-pager` on any command.

I use it on:

```
git --no-pager diff
git --no-pager log --oneline --graph --decorate --all -n 10
```

Then use an **alias** to avoid using (and remembering) long commands.

Answer (score 8):

I have this hunk in my `.gitconfig` and it seems to work fine (disabled for both diff and show):

```
[pager]
    diff = false
    show = false
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the oh-my-zsh, in the `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh` file, comment this line:

```
env_default 'LESS' '-R'
```

Comment: Hey, I think the OP wanted to have a command line switch to use single time with git diff, rather than a permanent global solution. Also, I don't know how good it would be to modify oh-my-zsh source code, since it would be hard to update oh-my-zsh later on. Better set that default value on your .zshrc file.

Comment: Thanks,you are right. If use the oh-my-zsh and need a permanent global solution, can add  `unset LESS` in the end of the .zshrc.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found the best for me was to set the following in .zshrc - `export LESS="-F -E -X $LESS"` I prefer not to mess with the files from oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 5):

By default git uses uses less as pager. I normally prefer more, as it will print the first page and then allow you to scroll through the content.

Further, the content will remain in the console when done. This is usually convenient, as you often want to do something with the content after lookup (eg.  email the commiter and tell him he introduced a bug in his last commit).

If you then want to pipe content, it would be inconvenient to scroll to print everything. The good thing with more is you will be able to combine it with pipeline and it will pipe through everything, eg.

```
# Find the commit abcdef123 in the full commit history and read author and commit message
git log |grep -C 5 'abcdef123'
```

Basically more is all you would ever need, unless you do not want the content to remain in the console when done. To use more instead, do as below.

```
git config --global core.pager 'more'
```

Comment: if you get ugly output with a bunch of highlighted ESC blocks at beginning and ending of lines then use these options to fix it back to color. worked great for me...

git config --global core.pager "more -MR "

and that is all you need to do

Answer (score 4):

For Windows it is:

```
git config --global core.pager ""
```

This will turn off paging for everything in `git`, including the super annoying one in `git branch`.

Comment: Works with Linux too!

Answer (score 4):

Just follow below instructions.

1. Just type `vi ~/.gitconfig` in your terminal.
2. Paste `LESS="-F -X $LESS"` line.
3. Press `:wq` and enter.
4. Restart your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised I didn't see this answer yet, but simply:

```
PAGER= git diff ...
```

---

Appendix A: I'm on macOS and using `zsh`, not sure if that changes anything.
Appendix B: As others have pointed out, this is not the best solution if you want to use this as part of a script or uncontrolled environment, where `$GIT_PAGER` might be set.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick-and-dirty script I wrote, I did it this way:

```
PAGER=cat git diff ...
```

Comment: This won't work if `$GIT_PAGER` is set. `git --no-pager` does the same but more reliably.

Answer (score 2):

The BEST pagination is `less -R -F -X`

```bash
# Global - all projects (if has no custom local pager)
git config --global core.pager '/usr/bin/less -R -F -X'

# Local - Only on project
git config core.pager '/usr/bin/less -R -F -X'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git -P diff
```

Or `--no-pager`.

BTW: To preserve colour with cat

```
git diff --color=always | cat
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to this, if you have a default pager set, and you want to create an alias that uses a different pager, you can use the `-c` option to pass the configuration parameter to just one command.

For example, I have [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) configured as my default git pager, but I can create a `lessdiff` git alias like this, for cases when I want to use `less` instead.

```
[alias]
    lessdiff = -c core.pager=less diff
```

Comment: How would you use the alias? I mean you do not define to which command the `-c` option is for. In which file do you declare it?

Comment: These lines go in your git [config file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Git knows that this alias config applies to `git` commands. You can edit the user's global git config like this: `git config --edit --global`, or you can set up system-wide or per-repo git configurations. I updated my answer to clarify that this is a git alias, not a bash alias.