# Ruby popen3 and ANSI colour

Tags: ruby, colors, ansi-escape

I am attempting to get watchr running tests automatically as files change, and got most of what I need working except for the fact that all ANSI colours from RSpec are being disregarded.  The offending code is as follows:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
stdout.each_line do |line|
  last_output = line
  puts line
end
```

When cmd is equal to something like `rspec spec/**/*.rb` then the above code runs RSpec fine except that all output is in monochrome.  I've looked at using `Kernel.system` instead, however system does not return the output which I need to determine if a test failed / succeeded.  How can I get the output form a script that is executed from within Ruby including the ANSI color and output this to the console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that rspec is examining the stream to which it is writing output to see if it is a tty (ie the console) or not, and if it's not, disabling colour. Many commands do this - GNU ls and grep, for example. Since the stream from the child process to your script is not a tty, colour will be disabled.

Hopefully, rspec has a flag which will force colour to be used, regardless of the stream type. If it doesn't, you will have to resort to some truly weird stty shenanigans.

Comment: Thanks Tom, you directed me in the right direction and I got it working by running rspec as follows: 'rspec --tty --drb --colour [path]' where obviously [path] is the path to the test(s) you are to run.  Thanks again, that is great.

Comment: It was the `--tty` argument that did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Chances are good that the `rspec` tool is checking to see if it is running interactively on a terminal or being run automatically from a script before deciding to use color output or not.

[The documentation](http://rspec.info/documentation/tools/spec.html) says you can force color with `--color` command line option.

Try: `rspec --color spec/**/*.rb`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the command that is being run by watchr is 'rspec --drb --colour --format nested [file_name_of_test]' so colour is being forced.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to run commands in a pseudo terminal via the [PTY module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) in order to preserve a user facing terminal-like behaviour. Credits go to the creator of the [tty-command](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command) gem ([see this issue](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command/issues/33)) who implemented this behaviour in his gem:

```
require 'tty-command'
cmd = TTY::Command.new(pty: true)
cmd.run('rspec', 'spec/**/*.rb')
```

Keep in mind that using a pseudo terminal may have unwanted side effects, such as certain `git` commands [using a pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager) which will essentially cause commands to hang. So introducing the functionality might be a breaking change.