# How can I preserve output color when executing a process in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, process, colors, exec, ansi-escape

I'm using a helper script to execute `rspec` tests.

```
command = "rake spec #{path} #{scope}"
output = `#{command}`
puts output
```

This works fine, except that I lose all the colors from the `rake rspec` output. The appropriate ANSI codes do not appear to be contained within the `output` string.

How can I execute a process so that it returns output which includes the text color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby popen3 and ANSI colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526842/ruby-popen3-and-ansi-colour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kernel.exec()` gets me the solution I want (colored rspec output), but it does so by *replacing* my ruby script process with the rspec process. That means I can't do anything with the `output` or run anything after the rspec call.

That's acceptable in my particular situation, but less than ideal as a general solution. So I'd like a better answer if available.

Answer (score 1):

RSpec will disable colour if it is not writing to a tty (i.e. the console).

In case of RSpec you can force colouring by `rspec --tty` or via rake by `rake spec SPEC_OPTS=' --tty'`.

See also [Ruby popen3 and ANSI colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526842/ruby-popen3-and-ansi-colour)

However this solution is still specific to Rspec. I'd be interested to hear a general one.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's possible to run commands in a pseudo terminal via the [PTY module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) in order to preserve a user facing terminal-like behaviour. Credits go to the creator of the [tty-command](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command) gem ([see this issue](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command/issues/33)) who implemented this behaviour in his gem:

```
require 'tty-command'
cmd = TTY::Command.new(pty: true)
cmd.run('rake', 'rspec')
```

Keep in mind that using a pseudo terminal may have unwanted side effects, such as certain `git` commands [using a pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager) which will essentially cause commands to hang. So introducing the functionality might be a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to replace your ruby process with that command, use `Kernel.system()` or `Kernel.spawn()` instead of a `Kernel.exec()`. Both of them execute your command in a subshell, `system` waits for the subprocess to finish, `spawn` returns its pid and you have to wait by yourself using `Process.wait pid`.

```
command = "rake spec #{path} #{scope}"
system(command)
```

or

```
command = "rake spec #{path} #{scope}"
pid = spawn(command)
# Some other stuff here
Process.wait pid
```