# Process full content of git blame

Tags: git

I'd like to process the full output of `git blame` on a specific file. Some of the files are too long to fit on the screen so the user is required to scroll down line by line by pressing the `Enter` key. Is there a command line option I am missing that would print out the full output? Alternatively, I could probably use the `-L` option to define the line start- and endpoints. However, this would require my the figure out how many lines the file has and run the command multiple times which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I think it only does the "Enter after each line" if your output is going to the console. So if you pipe it to another app, or redirect the output to a file, I think you'll get it all at once. Haven't verified this, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `--no-pager` arg:

```
git --no-pager blame file.name
```

Also, redirecting the output to a file will achieve the same effect:

```
git blame file.name > output.txt
```

You also have various ways of temporarily or permanently disabling git's paging with the `core.pager` config, and various environment vars.

See [How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to write it to a file. I'd like to process the output on the fly.

Comment: Ah, sweet. The option `--no-pager` is what I am looking for.