# Always use the pager for git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config

I'm using [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) as my Git pager.

If the `git diff` output is readable on one page, my Git prints the output to the screen.

Sometimes I'm too fast with typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (half page down), which kills my terminal. Is there an option to enable the pager for `git diff`, even if the output is very small?

This doesn't work:

- `git -p diff`
- `git --paginate diff`
- `git` settings: `pager.diff = true`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager/2183920

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is controlled by the `-F` (`--quit-if-one-screen`) option to less.

Git uses the options `FRSX` for/of less by default, if none are specified by the `$LESS` or `$GIT_PAGER` environment variables. To change it, specify the `core.pager` option and set it to `RSX`:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -+F'
```

---

Older versions of Git used to recommend the following in their documentation:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -+$LESS -RSX'
```

Comment: git does not use FRSX by default.  I suspect you are getting those defaults from the environment variable `LESS`, or from `GIT_PAGER`, which suggests another (imo simpler) solution.  Namely, ensure that `F` does not appear in `LESS` or in `GIT_PAGER`.  If git does use defaults when PAGER and GIT_PAGER are unset, that would surprise me, but perhaps I'm wrong about that.  Documentation?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The Git Documentation has been recently updated to disable options in a more backwards compatible way. My code was directly copied from the (old) man page – I have updated it now. The documentation also writes »Git sets the LESS variable to FSRX if it is unset«

Comment: @Leonmax: [git help config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

Comment: May want to add '-r' to enable interpreting ANSI colors.

Comment: `-E` is another nice option. It actually quits `less` if the page is less than a screen. I thought `-F` alone would do that, but you also need `-E` (`--QUIT-AT-EOF`).

Comment: You may also want `-c`, which causes the output to always start at the top and fill the screen.

Comment: I use [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) which by default uses options `-RFX` for less. This answer pointed me in the right direction, I removed the `-F` from the options and now get what I want.

Comment: Do not ever use `-r` unless you really know what you're doing, always prefer `-R`. I just spent like half an hour debugging this. "`-R`" means "pass through escape codes that less understands, and update less's model of the terminal." Whereas "`-r`" means "pass through all escape codes and ignore them; good luck." (This generally mangles the output in subtle ways.)