# `git` and `less` integration in OS X terminal: prevent writing output of `less` to tty

Tags: git, macos, command-line, terminal, less-unix

In OS X terminal, **when `less` is called on its own or by other programs like `man`, its output won't be written to the tty after we quit `less`**. For instance, if we run `less README`, we would be temporarily directed to a screen with things like

```
SO rocks.
README (END)
```

And after pressing `q`, the output of `less` would disappear, and we end up with something like

```
$less README
$    # shell waiting for input
```

However, this is not the case **if `less` is called by `git`** (the pager of `git` is set to `less -r` in my case). **The output of `less` is always written to the tty after quitting**. For instance, if we run `git log --oneline`, if the log is short `less` won't even be called; if the log is longer than one screen, then we would be temporarily directed to the output screen of `less` as usual:

```
0000000 set the pager of git to less
......
1111111 what's wrong with git?
(END)
```

And after pressing `q`, the whole thing gets written to the tty, so we end up with something like

```
$git log --oneline # OMG!!!
0000000 set the pager of git to less
...... (the entire log)
1111111 what's wrong with git?
$    # shell waiting for input
```

So it is possible to change this behavior? I mean, **is it possible to configure `git` so that it always pipes output to less (no matter the output is long or short), and leave nothing in the tty after `less` is quit?** Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...is it possible to configure git so that it always pipes output to less...

Yes. By default, `git` uses `less` as its pager, [with the options `FRSX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352049/always-use-the-pager-for-git-diff/12352224#12352224) [Apologies on the non-authoritarian source].

To get the behaviour you're after, you want to disable the `F` and `X` options. You can do this globally:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager 'less -+X -+F'
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18781512/1084945) for a longer explanation, and `man less`:

> -F or --quit-if-one-screen
>      Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.
>    -X or --no-init
>   Disables  sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

(I'm not sure why we want `-X` in this case, but apparently `git` uses it by default, and turning it off exhibits the behaviour you're after.)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I want. (And somehow I feel that this is the most intuitive behavior?) Thank you so much! I've bearing with the default behavior for almost two years... I should have figured out earlier.