# How to make git diff write to stdout?

Tags: git, terminal

By default `git diff` prints all `+-` lines to the stdout however I have a (devian) machine (which I connect through ssh) where `git diff` leads me to an editor (which I don't know which is) and I need to press <kbd>q</kbd> to continue.

I've checker git config and it looks like :

```
$ git config --list
user.name=XXX
user.email=XXX@XXX
color.ui=false
difftool.prompt=false
mergetool.prompt=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=XXX
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
$ git config --global --list
user.name=XXX
user.email=XXX@XXX
color.ui=false
difftool.prompt=false
mergetool.prompt=false
$ git config --system --list
'/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

Is there a place I am missing? Maybe the unknown tool is a fallback or something because I my machine is missing something? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager)

Answer (score 246, accepted):

By default, Git sends its diff output (and generally any output that may be more than a screenful) to the system's *pager*, which is a utility that prints only one screenful of output at a time. If you want to disable the pager when you run a command, pass `--no-pager` to Git:

```
$ git --no-pager <subcommand> <options>
```

This can be run for any Git command.

If you want to disable it by default *for diff only*, you can set the diff pager to `cat` by running:

```
$ git config pager.diff false
```

If you want to disable it by default *for all commands*, you can set the Git pager to `cat` by running:

```
$ git config --global core.pager cat
```

Comment: Didn't know about the pager. `git config --global core.pager cat` did it!. Thank you :)

Comment: @aaronbauman: Did you pass it to `git` (_not_ the subcommand)?

Comment: I see, "git --no-pager diff" is different than "git diff --no-pager". Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Same thing works for `git branch`, e.g. `git config pager.branch false`

Comment: OR add an alias in ~/.bashrc `alias git-np='git --no-pager'`

Answer (score 47):

The following `core.pager` value uses `less`, which prints to stdout, and also has pager functionality (if required), enabling scrolling up and down (unlike `cat`):

```
$ git config --global core.pager "less -FRSX"
```

It immediately quits if the diff fits on the first screen (`-F`), outputs raw control characters (`-R`), chops long lines rather than wrapping (`-S`), and does not use termcap init/deinit strings (`-X`).

Comment: Thank you.. I was looking for this option all over internet :)

Comment: This one is what I want

Answer (score 36):

You can also simply use `cat` for any `git` command if you don't care about the colors.

So `git diff | cat` for your case.

**Edit:** 
as pointed out in the comments if you do care about the colors use:

`git diff --color | cat`

Comment: And if you do care about the colors, do `git diff --color | cat` (:

Answer (score 2):

As [@mipadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17078021/5783745) points out, It's this simple:

```
git --no-pager diff
```