# Grunt Shell + Heroku Push = No stdout

Tags: heroku, gruntjs

Using Grunt to build, add, commit and push my code up to Heroku.

Build, add and commit are working great.

When I specify to "git push heroku master" in grunt shell I get no stdout while the process runs.

Here is the code in Grunt.js:

```
'git-push':             {
    command: 'git push heroku master',
    options: {
                failOnError: true,
                stdout: true,
                execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
             }
}
```

But I am only seeing the following when the process runs:

```
$ grunt push
Running "shell:git-push" (shell) task
Done, without errors.
```

I would like to see the output of the push while the push is in process.

Anyway to do this?

**Update: Full grunt shell script**

```
shell: {
    'git-add':              {
        command: 'git --no-pager add .',
        options: {
            stdout: true,
            execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
        }
    },
    'git-commit':           {
        command: 'git --no-pager commit -m "update"',
        options: {
            stdout: true,
            execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
        }
    },
    'git-push':             {
        command: 'git --no-pager push heroku master',
        options: {
            failOnError: true,
            stdout: true,
            execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
        }
    }
}
```

**Final Grunt Shell (working):**

```
shell: {
    'git-add':              {
        command: 'git --no-pager add .',
        options: {
            stdout: true,
            stderr: true,
            execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
        }
    },
    'git-commit':           {
        command: 'git --no-pager commit -m "update"',
        options: {
            stdout: true,
            stderr: true,
            execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
        }
    },
    'git-push':             {
        command: 'git --no-pager push heroku master',
        options: {
            failOnError: true,
            stdout: true,
            stderr: true,
            execOptions: { cwd: '../deploy'}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you don't get stdout for any git commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[How to make git diff write to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077973/how-to-make-git-diff-write-to-stdout)

Adding --no-pager as an option, gives output.

```
git --no-pager <subcommand> <options>
```

Also, certain git commands write to stderr,as discussed here:

http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-push-output-goes-into-stderr-td6758028.html

By including the flag and capturing stderr in the grunt task I was able to get output for the last part of the heroku push process (but not the part where the upload is tracked):

```
Fetching repository, done.

-----> Node.js app detected

       PRO TIP: Specify a node version in package.json
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
```

Comment: No effect - I still don't see the push stdout.  I have updated my question with the full grunt shell script I am using.

Comment: Add  stderr:true to the options.

Comment: Awesome work Robert!  Its working now, thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: I was trying to solve the problem for myself and camme across this, so it seemed right to post :).