# Why does git diff not work in the command line for me?

Tags: git

In a particular repository, I have unstaged changes in tracked files. When I run `git diff` in that folder, I get no output(and no error). However, if I use gitk(as myself) or run `git diff` as root, I can see the changes.

I've tried removing my ~/.gitconfig and all zsh config files, and also with bash.

Comment: What do you see in `git status`? Check your `.gitignore`s.

Comment: Does it happen for a new repo? Just run `git init`, `echo hello>test.txt`, `git add test.txt`, `git commit -m "hi"`, `echo world>>test.txt`, then check `git diff`

Comment: @slaks: Git status shows that the file has been modified. I doubt its a gitignore issue since it works with gitk and in shell as root.

Comment: Can you check ownership (and permissions) of files in the `.git` directory using `ls -alR`?

Comment: @CharlesB I'm experiencing the same problem with a new repository.

Comment: @krlmlr All the files are owned by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a problem with the pager (usually `more` or `less`) Git uses for outputing the diff.

Use `git --no-pager diff`, and check your PAGER environment variable.

Reference: [How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager)

Comment: AAH, that was it!, this was caused by less using -F but not -X. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe next time I should just post on SO before spending hours trying every configuration :P

Comment: Nothing is lost, you might have learned a lot trying and searching all these things :)