# Git diff: Write output and exit instead of interactive mode

Tags: macos, git, diff, interactive-mode

When I run `git diff` on my OSX command line, the output is displayed inside a `less` or `vim` interface. The interface lets me to scroll up and down, and quit using the <kbd>q</kbd> key.

This is very annoying, especially when there is no diff and git opens a blank screen.

Can I just write the diff (color) output the the screen without entering the interactive mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2183900)

Comment: Apologies, It is a duplicate indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Disable the interactive pager with the `--no-pager` option.

Usage: `git --no-pager diff` (note how it's not specific to git-diff, so it's usable with any git command!)

Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183920/2221472

Answer (score 17):

You can also use:

```
git diff --exit-code
```

Comment: +1 Is there a way to configure this as the standard behaviour for `git diff`?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Use:

```
git diff --color | cat
```

The `--color` is necessary, since by default `git` will not output colors if stdout is not a tty (with color support).

Answer (score 4):

I use this in some Makefiles with 'diff' and 'grep':

```
GIT_PAGER= git diff
```