# Disable "buffered view" when display 'git' commands results

Tags: linux, git, shell, buffer

I just switched to a new (already configured) development box.

Now `git` behaves differently, with some commands.

### Let me try to explain it:

- **before** (on the other machine) when typing `git log` I was getting the list of commits in my terminal. So I could just scroll up and copy/past SHAs as many times as I wanted.
- **now** (on the new machine) when typing `git log` I get a new buffer in the terminal, where I'm shown the commits. **Now** I have to *exit/quit* the result display pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>.
  After that the buffer is cleared and I come back to the terminal, but I **DO NOT** have any logged/buffered result in it; so I **CAN NOT** scroll up to see the result of the command.

To be more clear, now many `git` commands (`diff`, `log`, `reflog`, `show`, etc.) behave like `vim` or `man`, where the output of the command is in a separate buffer and the user **explicitly needs to exit this view to come back to the shell**.

Is that some kind of `git` configuration? Maybe a specified default editor? Or maybe is a operative system setting?

I was not able to find information (or the right keywords for searching the information) for solving this issue.

Comment: that is called a [_pager_](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144016/what-is-a-pager) and you may disable it as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will be useful to others (and more easy to find with non-specific search keywords!).
The solution seems to be about setting the **pager** of `git`.

The pager is the command that is used to display the `git` commands output.

In my case trying to run:

> `git config -l`

was not showing me any evidence of the current setting. But coming from a previous version I just assume that the **default value for the pager has been changed** to something different from `less` recently.
And with the new pager the screen is cleared after pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>, not allowing the the terminal buffer to maintain the output result.

Anyway I was more comfortable with the old pager: `less`, or no pager at all.

So I reset it with the command:

> `git config --global core.pager ''`

This will use **no pager** and will always show the output in the shell, allowing you to scroll up and copy/paste/check any part of the `git` commands output.
But is not nice whith `git log` because it will scroll down to the end of the list and will show the less recent commits.

So the perfect solution (for me) was to set it to `less`, **BUT ADDITIONALLY** I had to pass some options to it for defining the exact desired behaviour; so now I'm shown the list from the top, and then I can scroll up and see everything I output.

The final command I used is:

> `git config --global core.pager 'less -FRSX'`

(as explained [on the section *Better pager defaults* of this Atlassian documentation page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216040917/http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/08/whats-new-git-2-1/))

The fundamental in those settings is `-X` that prevents the screen from being cleared. While `-R` allows to maintain a colored output.