# Prevent empty pager in 'git diff'

Tags: git, terminal

When there are no changes in a git repo, `git diff` used to immediately return with no output. Since git 2.9, such `git diff` commands open a `less`-like window with no text, which I have to manually close by pressing `q`. Is there a way to restore the old `git diff` behavior?

**EDIT**

*Title changed.*

git 2.9 is actually unrelated, this new behavior is due to having recently introduced `LESS="-Ri"` in my environment. How should I change this variable to achieve what I want?

Comment: Very related with exhaustive answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager

Comment: `alias git='LESS= git'` runs interactive `git` commands in Bash with `LESS` set to nothing. Adapting to set it to something else should be obvious. Maybe `alias git='LESS="-F${LESS#-}" git'` to add `-F` but otherwise keep your global `LESS` options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `LESS="-RFi"`

From man:

```
-F or --quit-if-one-screen
Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.
```

If you don't want to change your environment `LESS` variable, you can archive the same via `.gitconfig`:

```
[pager]
    log  = less -FRX
    diff = less -FRX
    show = less -FRX
```

Comment: `LESS="-RFi"` seems to potentially break e.g. `git show HEAD`, but the pager options in `.gitconfig` work fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for

```
git --no-pager diff
```

the behavior should be the same again.

Comment: What if I do want the pager? I just don't want an empty one, is this possible?

Comment: @ital: I don't know pagers too well. I would say it depends. Sorry.