# How to configure git-diff so that long line not wrap around?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I sometimes have long line of code in git repo (e.g. a json config file), and `git diff` will generate output like below.

[image: long line]

On an EC2 instance, I `git diff` doesn't wrap the content to the next line, generating following output (I can use left/right keys to navigate), which I personally prefer.

[image: short line]

Does any one know how I can config the `git-diff` to change from one behavior to another?

Comment: If you are using `less` as your pager, set the `-S` option. (I like to think of S as standing for `Sideways Scroll`.) The defaults in Git are complex: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18781512/1256452. Note that setting `S` can interfere a bit with `F`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231427/162084

Comment: If the pager is `vi` or `vim`, then you can get same result of the `less` by doing `git diff | vi -` or `git diff | vim -` too.

Answer (score 2):

It's your terminal or pager program that wraps the lines, not `git diff`. Try redirecting the output of `git diff` into a file and open it with an editor that allows to control wrapping - you will see that the lines are not actually wrapped.

You can try this:

```
git diff|cut -c -$COLUMNS
```

Note however that it will disable colors and paging.

Comment: Passing `--color` to git diff will force colors again, but then the lines are visibly cut short before actually reaching '$COLUMNS', one char for each ANSI color char in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to torek's inline response above. Based on that, I realized I can do `git diff | less -S` to achieve what I want. It does better than the `cut -c -$COLUMNS` solution because it doesn't lose any context (I can still use left and right button to view all differences).