# Can't get git to automatically pipe diff/log to less (bash on windows)

Tags: git, pager, less-unix

Basically, I want git diff and git log to pipe to less automatically, so that my prompt isn't cluttered with code.

When I run "git diff", for example, I get the following output

```
WarriorPoet@JARVIS: /mnt/c/../Robot_one -> git diff
diff --git a/lib/movement/movement.cpp b/lib/movement/movement.cpp
index 523c2c1..3e323d6 100644
--- a/lib/movement/movement.cpp
+++ b/lib/movement/movement.cpp
@@ -1,6 +1,10 @@
// bunch
// of
// code
WarriorPoet@JARVIS: /mnt/c/../Robot_one -> _
```

My global .gitconfig has the following:

```
[core]
   whitespace = cr-at-eol
   excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
   pager = less -R
[pager]
   diff = true
```

and I have no local .gitconfig file that I know of.

EDIT:

running 'git config --global -l | grep pager'

```
core.pager=less -R
pager.diff=true
```

And running 'git config --local -l | grep pager' yields no output, while
'git config --system -e' is empty.

I am running Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, on windows 10.

Comment: Git doesn't pipe to less if the ouput size is less than the window height. Write more code :)

Comment: Interesting.. I've tried it with more output and still the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no local `.gitconfig` file that I know of.

You can check that with `git config -l --show-origin`

See if the project [stevemao/diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/stevemao/diff-so-fancy) can be of interest to cleanup `git diff`.

You can then use page to pipe its result:

```
git config --global core.pager "diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX"
```

That gives you:

> `git diff` vs `git diff --color | diff-so-fancy`

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/39191/13622719/7cc7c54c-e555-11e5-86c4-7045d91af041.png]

---

[ayorgo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755520/ayorgo) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871216/cant-get-git-to-automatically-pipe-diff-log-to-less-bash-on-windows/42871392?noredirect=1#comment122922801_42871392) to "[How do I prevent 'git diff' from using a pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager/2183920#comment27691311_2183900)"

```
 git config --global core.pager 'less -+F -+X'
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager/2183920#comment27691311_2183900) ended up working for me eventually. Otherwise my terminal would still get polluted with the output for some reason.

Comment: @ayorgo Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the repo where you want to diff, you can check *all* the config values (including local config values) with

`git config -l`

This will list the key value pairs.  You can additionally filter for the pager values with

`git config -l | grep pager`

to see if any local config values are overwriting your global config value.

Additionally if you are on an older version of git (I believe less than 2.8)  `git config -l --show-origin` won't work.  You can use, as a work around,

`git config --system -e`

`git config --global -e`

`git config --local -e`

to open your configured editor with the config file and find the location. eg if Notepad++ is your configured editor then the file location will display at the top.

Comment: I've edited my original question with outputs from these commands. I don't seem to have any additional .gitconfig files that override my global. Is this an artifact from me running bash on windows?

Comment: Does the git config --local -l without grep yield any results?  It needs to be run from within the repo to get any results

Comment: You can also set an environment variable for GIT_TRACE=true and see if git is actually executing your less command.  eg I get output like this  **run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'less -RFX'**