# Git diff showing output full of empty spaces and tildes (~) when there are no differences

Tags: git, bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

In any repository I run `git diff`, if there are no differences I get an output like this one:

```
(lots of empty space)
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

And if if press `q` it quits ok. If there are any differences, the differences show right, but also kind of padded by several `~` and empty space above.

The expected result would be for `git diff` to don't display anything if there are no differences, any idea what could be causing this?

In case it may be related, i recently installed `zsh`, but I tried running this with `bash` and the result is the same.

Comment: Are there DOS line endings in some files?

Comment: try `git --no-pager diff`.  I suspect you have set git to use a pager by default. The output you describe looks like pager output. [See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager)

Comment: yup, that was it. Thanks!