# How can I set multiple pager options for the same command in git?

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I want to be able to launch git diff with two different pagers on demand.

The only way I know is updating the git config and launching the command (or updating the *GIT_PAGER* variable).

Example of .gitconfig:

```
core.pager = cat
[Alias]
    def-pager = config core.pager cat
    diff1 = !git config core.pager less && git diff && git def-pager
```

That would let me launch *git diff* as default with cat pager and on demand launch *git diff1* and use *less* pager.

My question is: Is there any other way to do this without changing git config everytime?

Something like:

```
git --pager=cat diff
git --pager=less diff
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way

.gitconfig:

```
core.pager = cat
[pager]
   diff1 = less
[alias]
   diff1 = diff
```

This way you link the pager to the same alias.

By launching *git diff* you would use cat as pager and by launching *git diff1* you would use less as pager.