# Output All of Git Logs in One Go

Tags: git

I just got a new PC and am currently configuring my tools to how I like them. I've found that when I enter the command `git log`, I'm in "show git logs" mode so to speak where I have to press `enter` to show more logs. And once it's finished, I have to press `q` to exit back to the terminal. In my old PC, I had it where entering the `git log` command would just print all the logs in one go without having to exit back to the terminal. How do I configure Git to do this?

Comment: It's sending the output to a pager since it's bigger than one screen. `git --no-pager log` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager/2183920

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer from the link provided by @ikkentim's comment.

The command to make the change is: `git config --global pager.log cat`